# How to set data on a constructor correctly?

Tags: java, android, class, constructor

I want to set some ID Strings whithin a class with multiple names, so I think that I have to try to make a Constructor (At least, I think so). let me give an example to show what I want you to see. (I don't know if it's the best way to do what I want,

```
public class Music {

    private String Artist;
    private String[] Songs;

    public Music MarilynManson(){
        setArtist("MM");
        setSongs(new String[220]);
//How to set ID of songs?
    }

    public Music Slipknot(){
        setArtist("Slipknot");
        setSongs(new String[200]);
//How to set IDs of songs?
}

    public String getArtist() { return Artist; }
    public void setArtist(String artist) {Artist = artist;    }

    public String[] getSongs() { return Songs; }
    public void setSongs(String[] songs) {
        Songs = songs;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {}
```

Thanks you very much.

---

Hi again, sorry for my poor explanation... what I really want to try its for example: do click on a existing looping listview (Song 1, Song 2, Song 3) and that's why I want to get some ID(Strings) from another class, e.i (Something like this):

```
Anotherclass.java
.......
    MarilynManson.setSong[3] = "7362bf923";
    Slipknot.setSong[76] = "f9434gb394g7b";
```

Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "set ID"?  Do you mean the name of?  Or the value of?  Remember that variable names are just references, so elements in your string array are not named.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, set ID is for example like this one: String sweetdreams = "783645biefbwifñ";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Your class makes little sense. You try to set an id, yet you don't have a variable id to set.

```
public Music MarilynManson(){
        setArtist("MM");
        setSongs(new String[220]);
//How to set ID of songs?
    }
```

Since you give it a name, this is not a constructor, but a method that is expecting an instance of music to be returned. This is not what you want.

If you want to do it something like this, you'll need to create a method for each artist/song in the world.

what you want is:

```
public Music(String artist){
  this.artist = artist;
}

public Music(String artist, String[] songs){
  this.artist = artist;
  this.songs = songs;
}
```

of course, you'll need to add some getters and setters.

My advice: put Songs in a List, not an array, that way you can add songs without having to create a new Array each time.

After that, you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Music mManson = new Music ("Marilyn Manson", new String[20]);
  Music slipknot = new Music("Slipknot", new String[50]);
}
```

Just a thought: I would make it a List that takes type Song elements (a Song has a , a , ... ), rather than Strings.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I had removed what you did on void main before publishing hehe

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to have the same name as your class. So in your case your constructor method would be `public Music()`.

Now, you want to instantiate your Music class with `artist` and `songs`. To do this you need to allow your constructor to take in parameters. So your constructor now would be as below:

```
public Music(String artist, String[] songs){
    this.artist = artist;
    this.songs = songs;
}
```

And when calling your constructor you can go:

```
Music myMusic = new Music("Michael Jackson", {"Thriller", "Beat it"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think in Object Oriented way. In your problem you are talking about Three entities- Music,Artist and Song. So we can conclude something like this(this is what I thought):

> 1. One artist can sing many songs
> 2. One Music has one artist (which can be more than One,but in your case let it be One).

Instead of explaining lot, I think you can understand by following classes; how to solve such problems with proper approach. This is one way to solve your problem.You can design in your own way, (think in Object Oriented Way).

```
public class Song{
  int id; //id of song
  String songName;
  //getters and setters
}
public class Artist{
  int id;// id for each artist
  List<Song> songs;//songs list by this singer
  //getters and setters
}

public class Music{
   int id;// music id
   Artist artist;//artist
   //getters and setters
  //your logic...
}
```